# Protractor Chained Elements by Using Variables?

Tags: protractor

I am trying to keep my pageObjects in Protractor as clean as possible, but have run up against some behavior in selecting sub-elements.

This works:

```
var parent = element(by.css('.parent-class'));

parent.element(by.css('.child-class')).getText();
```

However this does not:

```
var parent = element(by.css('.parent-class'));
var child = element(by.css('.child-class'));

parent.child.getText();
```

Is there someway to do something like the second example? I'd rather not have the element locators spread throughout the methods on my pageObjects, but it seems thats the only way to locate subelements?

In actual application I have a long list of cards, from which I filter down to just the one I am looking for. I then want to do things with subelements of the card.

Comment: I have found something that looks to allow me to separate the locator info from the pageObject methods:
`var parent = element(by.css('.parent-class'));
var child = by.css('.child-class');

parent.element(child).getText();`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use the [`locator()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.locator) function to get the locator of the child element and use it to find a child of the parent. This is similar to the solution you provided in your comment, but allows you to define all properties on your page object as web elements instead of a mix of elements and locators:

```
var parent = element(by.css('.parent-class'));
var child = element(by.css('.child-class'));

parent.element(child.locator()).getText();
```

Comment: awesome. Just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

I have a lot of the following code:

```
var parent = element(by.css('.parent-class'));
var child = parent.element(by.css('.child-class'));

child.getText();
```

But as far as I understood you have a lot of children and you don't want to list all the variants.

Additionally to Nathan Thompson answer you can have a helper function in page object to find subelement:

```
function getCard(parent, child) { // Or getChild()
  return element(by.css(parent)).element(by.css(child));
}

function getCardText(parent, child) { // Or getChildText
  return getCard(parent, child).getText();
}
```

So then you can just write in spec:

```
expect(cardPage.getCardText('.parent-class', '.child-class')).toBe('...');
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to mention that using 5.2.2 version this implementation is bit different.
To get actual selector value you must use following code

```
let selector = child.locator().value
```

This is because locator returns an object which contains selector and other properties, but in this case, you only need selector.
here is what is returned by method locator()

```
name(name) {
  return By.css('*[name="' + escapeCss(name) + '"]');
}
{ using: 'css selector', value: '.child-class' }
```

Here is how it should be implemented now.

```
var parent = element(by.css('.parent-class'));
var child = element(by.css('.child-class'));
parent.element(child.locator().value).getText();

//short hand
var parent = $('.parent-class');
var child = $('.child-class')

parent.$(child.locator().value).getText();
```