# Clicking an element within a repeater using an existing locator

Tags: protractor, repeater

The app I am testing outputs a list using a repeater and I want to be able to find a particular row and the click on the edit button within that row.

I am using .filter to find the relevant row and then click on the edit button but this only works if I specify the locator for the button and not if I refer to an existing definition:

```
this.editWineButton = element(by.buttonText('edit'));

this.editWine = function (wineName) {
    this.wineListEntries.filter(function(row){
        return row.element(by.binding('wine.name')).getText().then(function(name){
            return name === wineName; 
        });
    }).then(function (elem) {   
    //THIS WORKS
        var button = elem[0].element(by.buttonText('edit'));
    //THIS FAILS
        //var button = elem[0].editWineButton;
        button.click();
    });
};
```

Having already defined the locator for the edit button what do I need to do to be able to re-use it with the result of the filter?

When I run the failing version of the code I get the error

"Failed: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined".

I feel sure the answer must be obvious but I cannot see my mistake.  Any suggestions would be very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `var button = elem[0].this.editWineButton;`, checkout this site on how to use `this` more effectively in javascript: http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/

Answer (score 0):

I tried igniteram1's suggestion of elem[0].this.editWineButton but it did not solve the problem.  However, I have found the solution.  The two key parts are using element.locator() as described in [Protractor Chained Elements by Using Variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30309620/protractor-chained-elements-by-using-variables).  Secondly, adding

```
_this = this;
```

The revised code is:

```
this.editWineButton = element(by.buttonText('edit'));

this.editWine = function (wineName) {
    var _this = this;
    this.wineListEntries.filter(function(row){
        return row.element(by.binding('wine.name')).getText().then(function(name){
            return name === wineName; 
        });
    })
    .then(function (elem) {   
        var button = elem[0].element(_this.editWineButton.locator());
        button.click();
    });
};
```