# Combining two element locators

Tags: protractor

I am trying to click an element(a specific column) in a row in a table.

This piece creats problem :

```
  this.clickEditForTheRequiredRow = function (panel, field) {
    var editRow = $('[ng-click="grid.appScope.requirements.editRowForCFSTP(row, rowRenderIndex)"]');
    var requiredRow = this.selectRow(panel, field);      
    requiredRow.editRow.click()
};
```

when i try to combine requiredRow with editRow, it throws an error as **can not click undefined**

But if i do :

```
  this.clickEditForTheRequiredRow = function (panel, field) {
    var editRow = $('[ng-click="grid.appScope.requirements.editRowForCFSTP(row, rowRenderIndex)"]');
    var requiredRow = this.selectRow(panel, field);      
    requiredRow.$('[ng-click="grid.appScope.requirements.editRowForCFSTP(row, rowRenderIndex)"]').click()
};
```

Now it is able to click the element as expected. What is the reason for this?

But is both the code represents the same? What am i missing to understand?

PS: this.selectRow() returns a row locator in a table

Comment: checkout this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30309620/protractor-chained-elements-by-using-variables

Comment: Thanks @RamPasala.. worked as expected